# I am trying to repeat an if statement using a while loop, but it keeps freezing

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, keyevent

So I am trying to make a game like Snake, but I am running into some issues.
I want to repeat the if statement inside of of the moveup class using a while loop, but
when I try to use the KeyListener to listen for the key press of the up arrow key to break the while loop it acts like it only looped once (moved up 5 pixels). The loop is supposed to make the snake continue going up without having to click multiple times, but it just moves five (the value I set it to do) pixels. Here is the code:

```
public class Snake extends JFrame implements KeyListener {
int ballX = 50;
int ballY = 50;
int playerX = 250;
int playerY = 250;
boolean up = false;
boolean right = false;
boolean down = false;
boolean left = true;

class DrawPane extends JPanel {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics gc) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int dotsX = rand.nextInt(500) + 1;
        int dotsY = rand.nextInt(500) + 1;
        Graphics g = this.getGraphics();
        setVisible(true);
        super.paintComponents(gc);

        gc.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        gc.fillRect(ballX, ballY, 10, 10);

        gc.setColor(Color.RED);
        gc.fillRect(playerX, playerY, 10, 10);

    }

}

public Snake(String title) {
    super(title);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    setContentPane(new DrawPane());
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.pack();
    this.setSize(500, 500);
    this.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.addKeyListener(this);
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        up = true;
        right = false;
        down = false;
        left = false;
        moveup(e);
    }

    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
        up = false;
        right = false;
        down = true;
        left = false;
        movedown(e);
    }

    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        up = false;
        right = true;
        down = false;
        left = false;
        moveright(e);
    }

    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        up = false;
        right = false;
        down = false;
        left = true;
        moveleft(e);
    }

}

public void moveup(KeyEvent e) {
    while (up) {
        if (playerX < 500 || playerX > 0) {
            playerX = playerX + 5;
            repaint();
            if (e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
                break;
        }
    }
}

public void moveright(KeyEvent e) {
    if (playerX < 500 || playerX > 0) {
        playerX = playerX + 5;
        repaint();
        // moveright();
    }
}

public void movedown(KeyEvent e) {
    if (playerY < 500 || playerY > 0) {
        playerY = playerY + 5;
        repaint();
        // movedown();
    }
}

public void moveleft(KeyEvent e) {
    if (playerX < 500 || playerX > 0) {
        playerX = playerX - 5;
        repaint();
        // moveleft();
    }
}

public void snakePanel() {

    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setBackground(Color.red);

}

public void ActionListener() {

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Snake r = new Snake("Snake");

}
```

}

Comment: I'm not a game programmer, but I'm guessing that you don't want your movement being handled that way. I would think that you just set the direction they are moving and have a timer event that moves in the correct direction at a set interval.

Comment: I've not been in java for long...but what I can see is that you have broken the loop after repainting moving up by 5 pixels

Comment: I'm not a event handler programmer but seeing this code occurs at going up. Why do you want to break out of the loop when you want keypress down going up by 5? You might as well not using loop in here?
`if (e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
                break;`

Comment: I think you need to do some reading up on Event Dispatching Thread

Answer (score 2):

It never loops because of the break. Effectively you're saying:

```
if keycode is up
  loop
    move up
    break if keycode is up // Will always be true
```

More so, you shouldn't be looping in an event handler like that. Event handlers should execute and return quickly else you'll block the event thread. Should be using a timer to act as a heartbeat and update the position/repaint periodically.

Answer (score 0):

**Keep in mind that you DON'T want to use Swing for more advanced games in the future.**

--- Quick solution:

Just remove your while(). The KeyListener interface lets you abstract the concept of "while this key is pressed, do this". Instead, when you implement the interface, you say: "whenever this key is pressed, do this". It's an event.

Here's your working code:

http://pastebin.com/b0CZDxpD

Comment: I understand what the problem is, I'm just looking for an alternative to it.

Comment: ok, so here's the thing: read the book (I dont want to be arrogant hehe). Heres the main thing: In a game, you have 2 basic loops: the Update() and the Render() loops.

In the first one comes the logic inputs, calculations (like damage, input handling, etc.). The second loop, the Render(), is what you call PaintComponent().

In a game, you have to process everything in terms of loops. You know the FPS term? It stands for Frames Per Second, which means: loops per second (rendering).

Comment: coding a game is somewhat different than coding normal software. In games you have to optimize the different numbers of things you want to process. Keeping that in mind, in your update() loop, which is a while(gameIsRunning), you want to read from keyboard and do some other stuff, like changing the snake's position. I'm editing my post to give you a better solution.